# How to get the raw value of an input tag inside a JQuery submit function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, encoding

I have a HTML form with an input box and a button. I bound a submit event on it, but when I try to match the value of the input box with the regex `(/\w+/)` I get inconsistent results:

1) It looks like it changes values to URI-encoded characters (e.g., it replaces spaces with +).
2) Even if it changes values to URI-encoded characters, how is it possible that the regex `(/\w+/)` matches + or other non-alphanumeric symbols?

How to get the raw value?

My JQuery code:

```
$('#form-send-username').on('submit', registrationFormListener);
function registrationFormListener(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($('#user-input-box').val());          // Print raw value
    if($('#user-input-box').val().match(/\w+/)) {     // Even matches non-alphanumeric characters
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to anchor the regex, i.e. `/^\w+$/`. As for the raw value, I don't see spaces being replaced with `+` (haven't test with your code, though).

Comment: Oh right! Thank you, that works. Regarding spaces replaced with +, if you submit a value including spaces, then the ajax form return a URI-encoded value. Anyway, now it's not a problem because I can check that with the regex you suggested. So, thank you again! Please put your comment in the answer box so as I can choose it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex `/\w+/` only checks whether there exists one* word character in the string.

<sup>* `\w+` matches one or more word characters, but as long as the string has one word character, a match can be found, thus validation is passed.</sup>

You need to anchor the regex with `^` (beginning of the string) and `$` (end of the string) to make sure the whole string consists of word characters:

```
/^\w+$/
```